# Не отображаются google fonts

Tags: html, css, google-fonts

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.3.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
body {
  font-size: 14px;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
ul,
li,
span,
a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul a {
  text-transform: none;
}
ul a:hover {
  text-transform: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a {
  color: inherit;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
.main-text {
  color: black;
  font-family: UnicaOne;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.delete-pad-mar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menumob {
  width: 123px;
  margin: 0 auto 55px;
  color: #fff;
}
.menumob__but {
  background: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 15px;
  border: none;
  background-image: url('/img/menubtn.png');
  margin-right: 20px;
  outline: none;
}
.menumob__menu {
  font-family: UnicaOne;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.menumob__ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #202020;
  padding-top: 120px;
  padding-bottom: 104px;
  opacity: 0.95;
  z-index: 40;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.menumob__ul > li {
  padding-top: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: UnicaOne;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
}
.menumob__ul > li ul {
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
.menumob__ul > li ul li {
  padding-top: 27px;
}
.menumob__ul > li ul li a {
  color: #6f6f6f;
}
.menumob_close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  right: 37px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: none;
  background-image: url('../img/menubtn_close.png');
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
.selected__item {
  border-top: 1px solid #434343 ;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #434343 ;
}
.theme {
  background-color: #202020;
  padding: 30px 94px;
}
.theme__block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.theme__about {
  color: #c3c3c3;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.theme__name {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'UnicaOne';
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-top: 3px solid white;
  border-bottom: 3px solid white;
}
.social a {
  color: white;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin-right: 27px;
}
.social a:last-child {
  margin-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1"/>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Unica+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css">

    <!--<script src="libs/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <ul class="menumob__ul hidden-md hidden-lg" id="mobile-menu">
        <button class="menumob_close"></button>
        <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="">CATEGORIES
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">TRAVEL</a></li>
                <li><a href="">LIFESTYLE</a></li>
                <li><a href="">FOOD</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CLOTHES</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">ABOUT ME</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="theme">
        <div class="menumob hidden-md hidden-lg">
            <button class="menumob__but"></button>
            <span class="menumob__menu">MENU</span>
        </div>
        <!--todo: сделать шрифт  -->
        <div class="theme__block">

            <span class="theme__about theme__about-postabl">Travel & Photo blog.</span>
            <div><h3 class="theme__name theme__name-postabl">Mundial</h3></div>
            <div class="social">
                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Делаю все как в инструкции:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
```

Делал также через @import. Шрифты подгружаются, но не отображаются. В Диспетчере видно что элементу соответствует прописанный шрифт в css. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если через Link то импорт не нужен. А можно HTML и CSS файлик

Comment: скинул в шапку начала html и css файлов

Comment: font-family: 'FontAwesome';

Comment: font-family: 'Lato';

Comment: .social a {
  color: white;
  font-family: FontAwesome; // font-family: 'FontAwesome'; Нужно так 
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin-right: 27px;
}

Comment: Я добавил одинарные кавычки, но не помогло. Спасибо. Что может быть еще?

P.S. Я разобрался, отсутствовал generic-family